# How to conditionally redirect to/display POST response data with Gravity forms

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm sending form data to a 3rd party via gravity forms. I'm trying to figure out how to process an XML response so that:

- If `<IsValid></IsValid>` returns the value True then redirect to the url within `<Redirect></Redirect>`
- Otherwise if  returns False then display `<ResponseDetail></ResponseDetail>`

I understand that it will need to be based off something like this:

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2 );
function post_to_third_party( $entry, $form ) {

    $post_url = 'http://thirdparty.com';
    $body = array(
        'first_name' => rgar( $entry, '1.3' ), 
        'last_name' => rgar( $entry, '1.6' ), 
        'message' => rgar( $entry, '3' ),
        );
    GFCommon::log_debug( 'gform_after_submission: body => ' . print_r( $body, true ) );

    $request = new WP_Http();
    $response = $request->post( $post_url, array( 'body' => $body ) );
    GFCommon::log_debug( 'gform_after_submission: response => ' . print_r( $response, true ) );
}
```